# What might case cause the development of biological nuclear weapons as a natural evolutionary adaptation of a species?

Tags: evolution, space, xenobiology, nuclear-weapons

Im doing a one-shot space campaign with some friends. One of the navigation hazards I wanted to add for my PCs was the system being infested with space Bourne biological life forms that, like some plankton species in real life use bio-luminescence as a form of mutually assured destruction, use biological nuclear weapons as a deterrent of space-borne predators. They will mostly be acting as mines that the players need to avoid.

However, I’m stumped as to how a biological species might evolve nuclear weapons in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

### Start with an electric organ

A number of different species, such as the electric eel, have [electric organs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_organ_(biology)) where many cells are stacked, which pass ions at one side to add up to a strong effect.  In this case, I'll start with an electric ray instead, because the shape seems, erm, marginally better preadapted for space flight, and because it sounds more intimidating to be attacked by a nuclear *[Torpedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_torpedo)*.

**Add uranium.**
This particular ray, which at some moment externally resembled the Earthly *Torpedo*, lived on a planet with an unusually high concentration of uranium in crustal sediments, whether due to the stars that preceded its planetary nebula, or some vagary of geological differentiation.  All of the life on that planet was highly resistant to radiation, maintaining four strands of DNA per chromosome as a fundamental genomic unit.  So although its prey concentrated uranium ions in their bodies, it was not much impacted by it.  Nonetheless, the heavy metal made it somewhat toxic to larger predators, so it came to accumulate large amounts, which served as a passive defense against larger sharklike organisms that evolved defenses against its electric jolts.  But they naturally kept up, developing a corresponding tolerance to the metal of their own.

**Enrich your life.** Life on this planet evolved somewhat more rapidly on Earth, and [natural nuclear fission reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor) were still ongoing in the background; there was more U235 on the planet, and also in a nearby asteroid belt, than on Earth.  So the *Torpedo* evolved a natural uranium enrichment process, selectively moving U235 through membranes of its electric organ one way, then returning all uranium back the other.  The process is quite inefficient and requires a lot of energy, but differences in the design of the proteins moving uranium forward and back all add up to the ray developing large reserves of lighter, more radioactive isotopes of uranium, to the extent that even the four-stranded genome of its predators was damaged.  During this evolution the ray protected itself with a range of the usual *[Deinococcus radiodurans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinococcus_radiodurans)* adaptations to improve its radiation resistance while accumulating the isotope.

**Warm-blooded fish.**  At this point the ray had started to become a very unusual animal.  A successful genus, it gave rise to species of great size, which produced sufficient heat from internal radioactivity that they could actually be warm-blooded *fish*.  These natural nuclear submarines became a terror of the seas - also of one another, as some of them turned on their own, immune to all the radioactive and electrical defenses.

With nuclear power in play, some of the rays developed the ability to shoot jets of superheated water to extract organisms and nutrients from the ocean bed, becoming massive scavengers that scraped the ocean floor.  To protect themselves from their own heat, and against the low salinity of freshwater estuaries, they evolved massive armored integuments that sealed their flesh away from all manner of harsh environments.  With these present internally in the spaces where water was heated, they eventually developed the ability to spray steam, permitting them to glide vast distances through the atmosphere, more even than flying fish, in order to escape their more ferocious cousins.

**Avoid nuclear annihilation**.  Uranium is a fairly poor nuclear explosive, requiring many kilograms of the purified isotope.  It was only when these rays reached their most massive size, processing vast amounts of detritus from the sea bed, that they accumulated enough uranium for a vigorous nuclear reaction.  The organisms evolved exquisite control over its nuclear moderation properties to scrupulously avoid fizzle yields, preferring a steady stream of power from a near-critical mass.

**Take to the skies.** All this heat required to evolution of elaborate cooling systems, initially involving seawater channels and robust pumps, but later moving air for cooling, which briefly was also co-opted as a method of air breathing.  This made our organisms capable of a prolonged airborne lifestyle, in which they could graze on flying mats of vegetation and hunt the associated flying herbivores.

**Space tourism.** In time, however, the nuclear lifestyle knew no bounds.  Space was scarcely more harsh than air, and offered a refuge from airborne predators comparable to that used by flying fish.  The habit of air breathing, relatively recently established in evolution, was supplanted by the use of ions produced from water by intense radiation.  The immense size of the rays' bodies permitted them to go long periods without eating or drinking.

**Conquest of space**. A turning point came when they reached the planet's rings.  The space rays were now able to devour large amounts of "CHON" (carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen) from a source never before exploited.  They still needed to return to the planet for trace nutrients and to breed, but they could not abandon the resources of space, so they became adept navigators with long-range senses.

**Watch the radar**. Their ancient electric organs had never been lost; the uranium enrichment was a homeotic adaptation of one duplicate of these structures.  The originals were still occasionally useful for attacking or defending in close combat, and when reduplicated, found many derived uses: mining nutrients, projecting radar signals, ion propulsion.

**Prelude to the Bomb**. As the *Torpedo* ecosystem processed more and more of the planet's resources, they needed to branch into nuclear waste reprocessing.  Artificial isotopes, plutonium to californium, were no longer rare, and their biochemistry needed to match.  These were concentrated in special structures that delivered more intense and controllable reactions.

**Deterrence**. Just so, the nuclear torpedoes finally evolved the *[initiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulated_neutron_initiator)*, the technical core of their nuclear arsenal.  Stocked with exotic isotopes with a very low critical mass, these replaced the bulky fission reactors at the core of earlier generations of eggs, allowing much smaller eggs to be laid and thus a substantial increase in reproductive rate.  But the system had another advantage:  any predator devouring more than one egg at a time would reach critical mass.  In time, even a single egg contained multiple masses of Cf-251, and could generate a fizzle yield with a simple muscular contraction.  Even as adults, these were organisms that would *not* fall victim to predators, because the same mechanism could be used to trigger the much larger uranium fission reactors on which adults depend for  power.

**Invasion**.  Eventually these animals evolved to lay a cluster of heavily shielded viable eggs, followed by a series of "mock eggs" filled with nuclear explosives and uranium with little other tissue besides a single triggering muscle.  This allowed them to generate multi-staged nuclear propulsion for their offspring, comparable to a (modest) implementation of the [Orion drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)).  Now they could cross the vast distances between planets, colonize passing comets, and even reach the system's Oort cloud.  If only the smallest fraction of the eggs ever survived, every step outward was a permanent increase in the size of the population.  From this beginning they seem bound to colonize nearby star systems, perhaps starting with one from which they periodically detect weak radio signals suggesting the presence of prey animals.

Comment: Objection:  If they're after nuclear power they want a critical mass, just not a prompt critical mass.  That's the realm reactors operate in.

Comment: You are not showing how they went from nuclear power to nuclear bombs.  That's an evolutionary gap that I do not think can be crossed.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - I added a bit more.  It's hard to fill in all the missing links in another planet's evolution - let me know if you need more. :)

Comment: You realize that the U-238 -> Cf-251 yield is under 1 part in 1000 and if you don't do a very careful isotope separation you end up with some Cf-252--prone to spontaneous fission, thus meaning that you get a criticality accident (Chernobyl was probably a criticality accident, but involving **far** more material), not a city-killing boom.  One egg with a Cf-251 critical mass in it means the animal used up many tons of uranium.  Just what is it's uranium source?!  And what did it do with all that heat?

Comment: @LorenPechtel these are fair points, but they don't seem like strong obstacles.  The planet and space have adults of multiple species producing and using nuclear power.  It's not obvious to me why spontaneous fission of Cf-252 would block its use in a biological initiator or reactor.  You're right about the amount being small, but the use of eggs here may occur under sporulation-like circumstances, a rare dispersal mechanism, while binary fission might be easier to keep the reactors burning locally.

Comment: The problem isn't fission per se, but fission produces neutrons.  Stray neutrons will set off your bomb as it's assembling.  The bomb destroys itself before full assembly and you just get a flash of radiation.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I doubt a biological nuke can be as efficient as a cast metal ingot in absolute terms, but I think its inefficient organization would offer alternate solutions to such technical issues.  It can control the charge, pH, temperature, and physical arrangement of fissible nuclei more readily.  Biologically, even a "flash of radiation" can be a deterrent to predation, though a more highly evolved explosion would be needed for other uses.

Comment: But you have described a creature that doesn't really care much about radiation.  And if the prey suicides that way I doubt it harms the predator at all.  There have been a few incidents of putting too much Pu in one place--the one I can recall the details on:  The guy was a few feet away, the "blast" knocked him down.  He got up and ran out of the building, collapsed, dying a few days later from the radiation.  That's what your muscle-powered Cf "bomb" will do.

Answer (score 1):

Evolution needs the individual bearing a certain feature to be able to survive and procreate.

Of course it's highly unlikely that anything alive and kicking might be able to be a nuclear bomb and then get a progenie after setting it off.

The only way around I see is that becoming nuclear weapons is a side effect of another useful feature.

For example, these organisms get energy by feeding on isotopes, which with their radioactive decay supply them with energy. If they feed too much on the right isotopes they might end up stocking a critical mass of those elements, leading to something similar to a [criticality accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticality_accident)

> A criticality accident is an accidental uncontrolled nuclear fission chain reaction. It is sometimes referred to as a critical excursion, critical power excursion, or divergent chain reaction. Any such event involves the unintended accumulation or arrangement of a critical mass of fissile material, for example enriched uranium or plutonium. Criticality accidents can release potentially fatal radiation doses, if they occur in an unprotected environment.

And generally their bodies would be highly radioactive, because of their diet.

Comment: “Evolution needs the individual bearing a certain feature to be able to survive and procreate.” That isn't necessarily true. If some of your offspring dying to kill predators means the rest survive then that is still an evolutionary advantage.

Answer (score 1):

## An insectoid like species that uses nuclear isotopes as fuel.

This is a species with different types of insect in different roles. Workers, soldiers, queens, etc. Some of them use nuclear isotopes as fuel.

## A suicidal worker caste couple.

They generate natural cores of radioactive isotopes. The older and more refined ones make larger cores, which allow them to fuel very expensive biological weapons.

## Aggressive mating.

They didn't evolve holes for sexual activity. They instead use a needle to inject others with sexual material. This has evolved in some to deliver the larger cores to each other. Two elderly insectoids shoving their cores together makes a big boom as it goes supercritical.